# ListBox with 2 kind of rows

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I use this code to create the `ListBox` in the `XAML` :

```
<ListBox Margin="20,96,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="ResultsListBox" SelectionChanged="ResultsListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And this is the code that i insert the strings(list is a `List` of String):

```
ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

Now i want the possible to create this listbox with array of items that contain:
string name
string id
string imageurl

Can i combine the this to kind of lists?

Comment: of course you can - two things observablecollection and stackpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class like this

```
public class SomeClass
{
   string name { get; set; }
   string id { get; set; }
   string imageurl { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your xaml like this

```
<ListBox Margin="20,96,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Name="ResultsListBox" SelectionChanged="ResultsListBox_SelectionChanged">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" /> <!-- ignore id if you don't want -->
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding imageurl}" />
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now, generate a collection or list to bind to the listbox

```
List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();
list.Add(new SomeClass() { name = "some name", id = "some id", imageurl = "some url" });
list.Add( .....);

ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: But i already have it for the string row(the DataTemplate) so can i use 2 DataTemplate?

Comment: I dont understand your comment. What do you mean by 'string row' and '2 DataTemplate' ? Anyway, I edited the above code, check and tell me if you still have a doubt